# Creating a custom payment method with conditional field

Tags: civicontribute, payment

So I understand that you can assign a payment processor any payment method - however - I am trying to create payment methods that replicate the behavior of Credit Card and Check.  For example - when manually adding Check or Credit Card contributions - you will then get a field for check number or last 4 digits of the card respectively.

If I make a payment method called *credit card - other*, I would want those credit card fields to also populate.

Is this hard coded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Themak, Nice question. This are hardcoded in core file but you can create your own field  for each payment method using buildform hook. Here is the snippet on how to do that

```
function custom_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
  if ($formName == 'CRM_Financial_Form_Payment' && !empty($form->paymentInstrumentID)) {
    if ($form->paymentInstrumentID == CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::getKey('CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution', 'payment_instrument_id', 'Test')) {
      $form->assign('paymentFields', array('source'));
      $form->add('text', 'source', ts('Source'));
    }
  }
}
```

> **Note:** The above snippet is not fully tested i have just created blindly, but i am 100% sure it should work